# C# How can I use HashSet values with ListBox?

Tags: c#, listbox, hashset

I'm currently working on a tournament manager for M.U.G.E.N. It reads the fighters from a SQL Server datatable and stores the rows in a ListBox. It should also randomly pick 16 fighters from it.

I've already created a Random generator and a HashSet - to prevent any duplicates - inside a while loop, so this process only stops, when 16 fighters have been picked. This is what I've written so far:

```
private void buttonRandom_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        /*
         * Randomly pick 16 fighters from the "Registered" ListBox
         * Only unique IDs are allowed
         */
    {
        Random contestantPicker = new Random();
        HashSet<int> fighters = new HashSet<int>();
        while (fighters.Count < 16) // Run Random until 16 fighters have been picked
        {
            fighters.Add(contestantPicker.Next(0, listBoxRegistered.Items.Count));
        }
    }
```

Now the question is: How can I use the numbers stored in a HashSet to copy items with their corresponding indices from one ListBox to another ListBox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After generating your `HashSet`, iterate through it and find corresponding items by their index.

Like this:

```
//old code
Random contestantPicker = new Random();
HashSet<int> fighters = new HashSet<int>();
while (fighters.Count < 16) // Run Random until 16 fighters have been picked
{
    fighters.Add(contestantPicker.Next(0, listBoxRegistered.Items.Count));
}

//list to hold fighter names
List<string> fightersList = new List<string>();

//iterate through all indexes in hashset
for (int i = 0; i < fighters.Count; i++)
{
    //show in output window
    Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("figther number {0}, named: {1}", i + 1, listBoxRegistered.GetItemText(listBoxRegistered.Items[fighters.ElementAt(i)]));

    //add fighters to list...
    fightersList.Add(listBoxRegistered.GetItemText(listBoxRegistered.Items[fighters.ElementAt(i)]));
}

//... and show it in some message box
MessageBox.Show(string.Join(", ", fightersList.ToArray()));
```

Comment: OK, after the for loop, I've changed the List to an Array and it shows the items with foreach. But it only shows System.Data.DataRowView. Even when I'm using ListBox.GetItemText(ListBox.Items) it just shows useless information.

Comment: it just shows one letter per row of what I think is System.Windows.Forms.

Comment: i have edited my code... now, I am using `GetItemText` from `ListBoxItem` with index i. Try it now.

Comment: Names of the fighters are now shown in the ListBox, but now I see that Random does not work properly. After pressing the button, it only shows the first 16 characters in order. I need the list to be completely random.

Comment: @ChaosSpindash ooops, my bad. Random works, and fighters hast set contains unsorted indexes of items in listbox (numbers from 0 to 15; for example: 6,3,11,8,0,1..) Error was with fetching names. I was accessing items by their index instead of fetching index from figters `HashSet`. Now it should work as expected.